SixJSymbol not triangular in basis transformation

The basis transformation is given by
$$\left| J^{P}, jd \right\rangle = \sum_ {S} (-1)^{J + L + Sd + Sq}\sqrt {(2 S + 1) (2 jd + 1)}\, \biggl\{\begin {array} {ccc} L & J & jd \\ Sq & Sd & S\end {array}\biggl\}\left| ^{2 S + 1} L_ {J} \right\rangle$$
J is the total angular momentum of the system.
jd is the total angular momentum of the diquark.
Sd is the spin of the diquark.
Sq is the spin of the heavy quark.
S is the total spin of the system.
L is the orbital angular momentum.
P is the parity of the state.
{} is the Wigner 6 j - symbol.
BasisFunction[J_, jd_, Sd_, Sq_, L_] := Module[{sum, term}, sum = 0;
  Do[term = (-1)^(J + L + Sd + Sq)*Sqrt[(2*S + 1)*(2*jd + 1)]*
     SixJSymbol[{L, J, jd}, {Sq, Sd, S}];
   sum += term*QuantumState[2*S + 1, L, J], {S, Max[0, Sd - Sq], 
    Sd + Sq}];
  sum]

But this is giving me SixJSymbol is not triangular error instead of 1 equation in the image. I would like to know what am i doing wrong.
BasisFunction[1/2, 0, 1, 1/2, 1]


Shouldn't there be SixJSymbol[{L, Sq, J}, {S, Sd, jd}] instead of SixJSymbol[{L, J, jd}, {Sq, Sd, S}]? And you can silence the error message, which appears when the result is zero, with Quiet: Quiet@SixJSymbol[...].

The expression in eq i wrote was wrong. I made the correction. The ans is not supposed to be zero, it should give me the first eq in the image. I tried SixJSymbol[{L, Sq, J}, {S, Sd, jd}] as you mentioned and it gives me the first term but with a neagtive sign. It means the problem is in position of terms in sixjsymbol. thank you for pointing out the mistake in expression.

Please give us a reference to your basis transformation formula. You likely mixed up some terms, so this really doesn't seem like a Mathematica issue ... :)

And it also doesn't seem to be the order of variables in SixJSymbol, because whichever permutation you take, you always get the negative sign.

The expression i have used is form link. If i use the expression from link i get the equations with proper magnitude but not sign.
